# Limit to openmp for iterator

Tags: c++, for-loop, openmp

I'm trying to run an openmp for loop over a large number of iterations, and it seems it dies when the number of elements it loops over reaches a certain value, specifically 2147483647.

There is no problem in doing a serial loop over this number of elements, so I can only assume it's to do with some internal openmp indexing.

Example code:

```
int n = 33;
int tau = 0;
long long int maxVal = floor((pow(2,n)-2)/2);
#pragma omp parallel for shared(tau)
for(int i=2;i<=maxVal;i++){
    tau++;  
}
```

With n = 33 tau does not change, showing the loop didn't run (and there is no cpu usage). For n <33 it runs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you use `int` for a counter when the upper bound is `long long`?

Comment: @C.R. Because he wants to create an infinite loop.

Comment: Despite the sarcasm not being useful, the observation is. That seems to be the ticket, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're experience is integer overflow.

`2147483647` is the maximum value for a 32-bit signed `int`.  So for any `n` for which `n < 33` is true, `floor((pow(2,n)-2)/2);` evaluates to some positive value less than `2147483647`.

Starting at `n = 33`, you'll get integer overflow, and in the specific instance of `n = 33`, the result is that you're saving a negative value to `maxValue`.

As such, `for(int i=2;i<=/*some negative value*/;i++)`, you never enter the body of the loop because `2` (`i`'s first value) is greater than all negative values.  (`i<=maxVal` returns `false` on the first check.)

You could use `long long unsigned int` to get a larger high end on values that you can handle.  If you overflow this, you'll have to come up with some other solution.

Comment: If I remember correctly, OpenMP requires signed integer types to be the loop counter.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenMP, so that may be the case... but regardless, the problem he's experiencing is integer overflow.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I'm using mpz elsewhere in the code for large integers as well, so I'll see if openmp can deal with those.

Comment: Type coercion in C is always to the bigger type, therefore the comparison in the loop would be `(long long)i <= maxVal`. This is always true (for `n >= 33`) since `i` would simply wrap to negative values once it reaches the maximum value for `signed int`.

Comment: @C.R., OpenMP requires _signed or unsigned integer type_, which includes `long long int`. `long long` is considered simply as a modifier to the integer type.